# Paypal Transaction with Rupees not in Dollar

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I integrate paypal as a payment gateway in my site.But all of the visitors of my site are India. They need to do transaction in rupees not in dollar. Can anybody guide me,how to do that in paypal??

Comment: Have you Googled `paypal pay rupees`?

Comment: Also, you need to state what type of payment integration you are using? i.e Forms or direct.

Comment: This article seems interesting: http://imtips.co/pay-indian-rupees-paypal.html

Comment: Are you aware paypal don't allow indians to pay to another indian account? and i don't think paypal have the option to process payment in rupees.

Comment: I think that It's not supported :(
https://cms.paypal.com/mx/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_currency_codes

Comment: How about you show the conversion price in rupees so that your customers know how much money is being deducted off them. off course, to keep it real-time you need to have an API do that for you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PayPal would only supports specific currencies, and not all currencies are supported for each of PayPal's different products/services.  You can find a list of the supported currencies via the different products [here](https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/240/kw/supported%20currencies).